# Instagram Api error code 400 invalid response type

Tags: api, instagram

I am trying to authenticate the user by clicking on the **"login with Instagram"** button. but getting this error:

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid response type: "}
```

**This is OAuth I am using:**

```
<a href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?app_id=<?php echo APP_ID; ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo urlencode(REDIRECT_URI); ?>&scope=user_profile,user_media&responce_type=code" >login with instagram</a>
```

**I am following this guide:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions

I check the error code list but unable to verify what that this error exactly meant to, I just strictly following the guide. If anyone familiar with this issue before would love to see your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Oops! My bad just typed mistake respon**c**e_type=code instead respon**s**e_type=code